# How can I create a dependent pick list on a visual flow page?

Tags: visual-workflow, dependent-picklist

I have 2 pick-list fields on an object, that are dependent to each other.

How can I create such connection on a visual-flow screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By following these steps you can show your Controlling and dependent piclist on Visual flow.

- Controlling picklist will be in Screen 1 and Dependent picklist will
  be in child screens of Screen1,
- Based on the selected value in controlling picklist, go the
  corresponding screen ( by putting decision box in between)
- We can remove 'Required' Line from Dropdown, edit the screen > double
  click on right side drop down, on left you can find an option to
  change

Let me know if this solves the problem!

Comment: what about creating a VisualForce page with Field-dependent picklists and integrating the VF page into the Flow? Is this something that Flow supports?